# How to exclude getters and setters?

Tags: javascript, typescript, generics, typescript-generics

Consider the class `Foo` below:

```
class SomeClass {

}
class Foo {
    readonly foo: string
    readonly baz?:string
    private someclass: SomeClass
    set bar(v:boolean){
       // th    is.foo = v
    }


    getFoo() {

    }

    constructor(json: FooLike) {
        this.foo = json.foo
        this.baz = json.baz
        this.someclass = json.someclass
    }
}
```

My goal is to obtain interface something like this

```
interface FooLike {
    readonly foo: string,
    readonly baz?:string,
    someclass: SomeClass,
}
```

How to remove all methods, getters and setters?

I tried this:

```
export type NonFunctionPropertyNames<T> = {
    // tslint:disable-next-line:ban-types
    [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Function ? never : K;
}[keyof T];
export type NonFunctionProperties<T> = Pick<T, NonFunctionPropertyNames<T>>;


    let z: NonFunctionProperties<Foo>
```

But this does not remove the setters/getters

Comment: I'm not sure if this is doable.  This is the interface of `Foo`: `{
    readonly foo: string;
    readonly baz?: string | undefined;
    bar: boolean;
    getFoo: () => void;
}`

Comment: Typescript considers `bar` to be a `boolean` property of the class and actually lets you access it `const foo = new Foo({foo: 'a', baz: 'b', someclass: new SomeClass()})
const bool = foo.bar; // type boolean
console.log(bool); // logs undefined`